# Run expressjs on Vagrant Scotch-Box

Tags: node.js, express, ssh, vagrant

I am using a preconfigured Vagrant Box named [scotch-box](https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box) and want to run `expressjs` there.

The first thing I did is to `npm install -g express-generator` and when I try to run it on my browser, it doesn't work because the IP Address of the Vagrant Box is always `http://192.168.33.10/`. How can I make it work like just typing `localhost:3000` on my browser?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the IP directly and indicate your port `192.168.33.10:3000`

If you do not use the IP, you will need to forward port in your Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  blablabla some configuration

  # forward port for node app
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  continue blabla
end
```

so you will be able to access `localhost:3000` ?

Comment: Where will I put the line on forwaring a port? In the Vagrantfile?

Comment: and should I comment the line config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "127.0.0.1:3000" or not anymore? Thank you. Will try it now

Comment: if you have such line `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "127.0.0.1:3000"` yes remove, to have IP it should be `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`

Comment: Thank you again. If you don't mind, can I ask something? I'm using windows for vagrant and how can I be able to remove everything after vagrant destroying?

Comment: `vagrant destroy` will destroy everything incl VM files. the only thing remains in the base box but you should keep it for future usage of vagrant

Comment: And lastly, every project I git clone https://github.com/scotch-io/scotch-box.git project-name -- is this even correct? or should I just change my files on the public folder.

Comment: no its better to keep a separate project workspace for each of your project (and potentially with their VM, if you have space or can run an external HD) so that you keep history of all your different projects and can alway refer to them by `vagrant up` in the specific folder